# Detect IPv6 in PHP?

Tags: php, ip-address, ipv6

I am currently detecting the user's IPv4 address and using IP blocks with the v4. However I want to capture the IPv6 and have block lists for this too, so the question is:
Is it the same logic to get IPv6 as IPv4 or something different in PHP? I am just not sure if every device has a IPv4 and IPv6 or is it either one of these and the system will auto detect what format it is and store it?

Answer (score 6):

Apache reports the `REMOTE_ADDR` to PHP. If Apache listens on a v6 interface it is going to be the v6 address.

It is easy to differenciate. IPv4 addresses will always have a fullstop `.` character and IPv6 addresses will always contain a colon `:`.

When creating blocklists (or whitelists) you should be careful handling the v6 addresses. They can be shortened by using two consecutive colons `::`. There is no guarantee that your OS will use the shorter or the full form, so your script must handle that. Check [Wikipedia's IPv6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ipv6) page for details.

Comment: [`inet_pton`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.inet-pton.php) will parse both families into a binary string and you can determine the family by the length of the string.